# jQuery Validation Plugin: validate decimal number with comma as decimal separator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <label for="field">Required, decimal number:</label>
    <input class="left" id="field" name="field">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C3Ncf/1/

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working, I'll test if the numbers are introduced correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the pattern rule to pass a custom regex pattern like

```
$("#myform").validate({
    //for debug only
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^(\d+|\d+,\d{1,2})$/
        }
    },
    messages: {
        field: {
            pattern: 'Please use the proper pattern'
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C3Ncf/)

---

If it is a repeated pattern create a custom validation rule

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("mynumber", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(\d+|\d+,\d{1,2})$/.test(value);
}, "Please specify the correct number format");

$("#myform").validate({
    //for debug only
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            mynumber: true
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5nuk8/)